# SAS %while loop condition not evaluating correctly

Tags: sas

I'm running a macro loop to recursively strip out stock returns greater than the 99.5 percentile to calculate a volatility model. I'm trying to set the loop to run until there are no observations with a z-score (assuming standard normal for the percentile) greater than 2.58. For some reason though, the loop will not evaluate despite the condition being true.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
%macro delete_jump;
    %let z_max=10.0;
    %let i=0;
    %let crit=%sysfunc(quantile(%str(NORMAL),0.995,0,1));

    %put The critical value is &crit.;

%do %while((&z_max. > &crit.) and (&i. < 30));
    %put max=&z_max.;

        proc expand data=crsp_data out=crsp_data(drop=time);
            convert ret_nojmp=ret_vol / transformout=(movstd &hist_pd. trimleft &hist_pd.);
            convert ret_nojmp=ret_ma / transformout=(movave &hist_pd. trimleft &hist_pd.);
            by ticker;
        run;

        data crsp_data(drop=ret_vol ret_ma);
            set crsp_data(drop=zscore);
            zscore=(ret_nojmp-ret_ma) / ret_vol;
            if quantile("NORMAL",0.01,0,1) < zscore < quantile("NORMAL",0.99,0,1) then ret_nojmp=ret;
            else ret_nojmp = .;
        run;

        proc sql;
            select max(abs(zscore)) into :z_max
            from crsp_data;
        quit;

        %let i=%eval(&i.+1);
    %end;

%mend delete_jump;
```

I set z=10 to initialize the loop and i is just a counter so I can escape after a certain amount of time. When it gets to that point though, the log file says the following:

```
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  %LET (variable name is Z_MAX)
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  %LET (variable name is I)
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  %LET (variable name is CRIT)
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  %PUT The critical value is &crit.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable CRIT resolves to 2.57582930354889
The critical value is 2.57582930354889
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Z_MAX resolves to 10.0
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable CRIT resolves to 2.57582930354889
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 0
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  %DO %WHILE((&z_max. > &crit.) and (&i. < 30)) loop 
      beginning; condition is FALSE.  Loop will not be executed.
MLOGIC(DELETE_JUMP):  Ending execution.
```

I've tried splitting the conditions and hardcoding the value of CRIT, but it never executes the loop.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Did you re-compile your macro before each run after making your changes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `%do while` uses `%eval` internally, which only works properly for integer comparisons, but you are comparing two decimals. Replace as follows and it should work as expected:

```
%do %while(%sysevalf(&z_max. > &crit.) and (&i. < 30));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for the advice!